# sql counting values in 3 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, count

How do I count all values when the possible values could be in anywhere from 0 to 3 columns. I want to add up all the a's, b's, c's, d's

```
COL1     COL2     COL3
a
b
b         a
a         c        b
a         b
c         a   
d         a        c
c         d
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
select col, count(*) 
from (
select col1 col from tablename
union all
select col2 from tablename
union all
select col3 from tablename) t 
group by col
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT t.Val, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
  FROM mytable
  UNPIVOT (
     Val FOR Col IN ("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"))) t
GROU BY t.Val
```